# Compound line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to easily plot a compound line with matplotlib? Just for clarification, by compound line, I mean a double-line or similar. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean plot more than one dependent variable on the same axes against the same independent variable?

Comment: Not exactly. Let's say that there is only one dependent variable (I have many but just for the sake of discussion), the plot would show two or more lines. I'm just trying to replicate what Excel does where, for any line graph, you can edit the line and select a different line compound (similarly to line style or width).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, AFAIK. You can see a list of styles available [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html).

That being said, you can simulate a double-line by plotting another line by adding a small offset to your original line in the Y-direction.

Comment: Hi @Priyatham. That is exactly what I was trying to avoid for 2 reasons: (i) to keep the code as short as possible; (ii) it's not so simple to offset when you have a logarithmic scale as in one of my graphs. Thanks.

Comment: @afernandezody So if you have a logarithmic scale you just multiply instead of adding. (Probably by something close to 1 in this case.)

Comment: @afernandezody Clearly some proper solution involving line style, if available, would be much better. I'm just saying that log scale isn't necessarily a show-stopper for using this hack.